# Invalid Assignment Operator java

Tags: java, assignment-operator

Here is my code:

```
h[ht] * sth -= 3;
```

the " * " gives me an error:

> Syntax error on token "*", invalid AssignmentOperator

I need the value of h[ht]*sth to be reduced by 3

Comment: if you are try to do something like you do in `c` with pointer, then `java don't support pointers `

Comment: What is the value of `h[ht]*sth`? How can it be reduced by three? What is in the array? What are you trying to do?

Comment: is this `h[ht] * sth` a valid variable name?

Comment: and tell us more  `h[ht] * sth -= 3; ` give some detail coding

Comment: `xxx = h[ht] * sth - 3;` where xxx should be `h[ht]` or some other variable.

Comment: If the talk is about float values, you can do this: `h[ht] -= 3 / sth;`

Comment: What were you expecting -= to assign the result to?  The LHS has to be a reference that the result is assigned to.  As written this makes no sense to me or the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is invalid because "-=" is actually a contracted form:

```
int a = 1;
a -= 1;
// the above line is the same as:
a = a - 1
```

Assign the computation to something else:

```
int a = (h[ht] * sth) - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying is syntactically incorrect.

I suppose  `h[ht]` and  `sth` are two different variables and you want to reduce their result by 3.

basically this is Compile time error, therefore this not able to compile. Right?

in order to achieve this you need to break it into two different statements i.e.

```
int/long/float/double temp =  h[ht] * sth;
temp-=3;
```

or you can achieve this like this also `( h[ht] * sth )-3`

and you will able to achieve what you want to do.

Please read [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and let me tell you Java's compiler is implemented using this grammar, therefore if any statement is not following these grammatical rules, result into syntactical error.

I hope your issue will be resolved.
Thank you